# wmq: how to create queue via mq client connected to queue manager

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

I am running queue manager QM1 on am-wmq-ux01:1414, mq client is running on am-wmqc-ux01. I would be interested how can I create new mq objects on QM1 using mq client connection from am-wmqc-ux01?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [SupportPac MO72](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO72).  It is a client-based version of runmqsc called mqsc.  If you are suitably authorized (or if nobody bothered to secure the QMgr) then you can do anything with mqsc that you can with runmqsc.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for your input. +1 for you I have found the same information about support pack will mqmonntp should do the trick.